# Change NGUI topAnchor in UIPanel using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am trying to figure out how to, via c#, change the topAnchor point in my UIPanel.

Here is how I am trying to go about it:

```
// The GameObject I want as my new Anchor //
GameObject searchField = GameObject.Find("UI_InfinityScroller/SearchUser");
Transform s = searchField.transform;

// The gameobject in which i want the new Anchor Point //
UIPanel test = GameObject.Find("UI_InfinityScroller/ScrollView").GetComponent<UIPanel>();
test.topAnchor.target = s;
```

This does nothing. it does not change my topAnchor? I am not sure what i am doing wrong and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: do you maybe have "Run only once" flagged on the anchor component? edit: oh nvm, didnt see that its a panel

Comment: What is your intended outcome here? Are you trying to resize the panel based on switching the Anchors?